# Socksify like program for Fedora?

Tags: linux, networking, socks

I need a program that allows me to pass an application through a socks server, even if the program does not have native socks support. Under Ubuntu I can use socksify for this. What can I use under Fedora?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I think Fedora packages `tsocks`](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/tsocks), which works similarly.

Comment: The link no longer works and at least for Fedora 36, the tsocks package is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the source for socksify and rebuild it under Fedora, if you can't find a Fedora package.  On Ubuntu where you using socksify provided by [dante-client](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/dante-client)?  If so, then the download for the source can be found on the [Dante home](http://www.inet.no/dante/).