# VPN like solution for SSH Tunneling?

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, socks

[Socksify like program for Fedora?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13021/socksify-like-program-for-fedora)

Socksify, tsocks, proxycommand in ssh, they're great softwares/solutions that can be used to "constrain" given apps to use a SOCKS5 proxy (what was created with an SSH TUNNEL). Even if the given apps doesn't support to use SOCKS5.

But: Are there any solutions to use an SSH Tunnel to "constrain" all the traffic on a PC to it? So it would be like some "kind of a VPN solution". So all the traffic from the PC would go through **only** in the SSH Tunnel.

Are there any solutions for this? It would be a very-very-very good feature.

p.s.: because installing OpenVPN vs. Installing SSHD+restrict a ssh user to only have "ssh tunneling" permissions is much simpler...

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just found a new solution for this recently that is REALLY neat. Take a look at sshuttle.

https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `sshuttle`, +1

Comment: I wonder that are there any ports to win7? :D (Linux user:P)

Answer (score 1):

You can build VPN-like tunnels with SSH.  The concept is essentially, connect your external network interface via ssh to some target machine.  Create an internal only network interface.  Change routing so that all traffic goes over the internal interface and hence out via the external tunnel.

Here's one tutorial,

http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/VPN-Over-SSH

and a more complex one,

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/539

and another,

http://www.eth0.it/2008/06/09/ssh-vpn/

Comment: thank you, but I think you're solution is TCP over TCP. sshuttle isn't tcp over tcp afaik.