# Put `ForceCommand` in a user-specific configuration file

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, ssh-config

I'm trying to [restrict an SSH-tunnel user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14312/how-to-restrict-an-ssh-user-to-only-allow-ssh-tunneling/337445#337445).

```
# sudo cat /home/user/.ssh/config
Banner none
ChrootDirectory /home/%u
PasswordAuthentication no
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding no
AllowAgentForwarding no
ForceCommand /bin/false
```

However, none of these seem to have any effect.

When I prepend `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` with `no-pty,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="/bin/false"` it works, but I'd like to also include these directives into permanent configuration.

Is it possible to restrict a user this way without updating `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

**UPDATE** I know about `Match User` and `Match Group`; the point is to have this in a *user-specific* config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `/home/user/.ssh/config`, that's purely for ssh client itself, used on the machine *initiating* the ssh connection.  So not useful here.

Question has been updated saying you've discounted the prospect of adding `Match User` or `Match Group` entries into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, because you want a user-specific config.

If you want certain users to be chrooted into their home directory, you could leverage group membership instead, such as this, specifically using `Match Group` and `ChrootDirectory %h`.

```
Match Group jailed
  Banner none
  ChrootDirectory %h
  PasswordAuthentication no
  AllowTcpForwarding yes
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  ForceCommand /bin/false
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen this, but I'd like to avoid editing `/etc/sshd_config`, if possible.

Comment: Can you please add the "*only used by the ssh client, on the machine initiating the ssh connection, so ignored by sshd*" part to your answer? (Because it actually answers.) If I attempt to do that, it'll probably be rejected by the mods

Comment: As for the `Include` - I thought about it, and even tried it, unfortunately it doesn't work. I'll post some more info as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # sudo cat /home/user/.ssh/config
> ```
>
> UPDATE I know about `Match User` and `Match Group`; the point is to have this in a user-specific config.

Something like `ForceCommand` works to limit what the user can do. That doesn't work well in a configuration file placed in the user's home directory, since they would almost certainly be able to change the configuration, or at least to make it inaccessible (e.g. `mv ~/.ssh ~/.ssh_disabled`).

Of course, `.ssh/config` is also the configuration for the SSH *client*, that is, it modifies what happens when you make an SSH connection *out of* that system. Restricting a user must necessarily happen on the server, and `sshd_config` is the only place where `ForceCommand` is documented to exist. Also, as you say, `Include` only exists for the client configuration, so your options are a) put the `ForceCommand` in the `sshd_config` of the machine with a suitable `Match` command, or b) don't put the  `ForceCommand` anywhere.

Of course, you could put the SSH server's configuration together from distinct files with some external system, the simplest of which would be something like
`cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf > /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind: use the [`Include` directive](https://superuser.com/questions/247564/is-there-a-way-for-one-ssh-config-file-to-include-another-one).

However, it [only works inside the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`](https://lists.gt.net/openssh/dev/68180) (ssh as a client), and when called in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (ssh as a server), [throws a "*Bad configuration option: include*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371489/ssh-config-line-1-bad-configuration-option-include/52010162#52010162) error - apparently, [it was only implemented for the client side](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=631189#20)

Problem is: the directives I need (such as `ForceCommand`) are for the server side, therefore ignored when added to `ssh_config`.