# Removing commands from a specific user

Tags: debian, permissions, account-restrictions, mysql-connection

I have a problem, I need to give an access to someone, but the only way to connect to the database is via SSH, so if I have understood everything correctly, I need to create him a linux account (on a Debian 10 machine), the user created doesn't have any right to write in folder, so I guess he can't break anything.

But the problem is that he can read any file in the filesystem, I don't really know what is the best practice, I know chmod could fix everything but I don't know if it is a good practice to remove all rights from others and changing the group of every single file to my main linux account.

I guess I should remove all the execution rights of the command under the /bin folder and change the group of the file?

Thanks for reading! I hope I was clear.

Comment: Welcome! Never change permissions/ownership of system's files!

Comment: Ok seem logic but what to do to make a user having no read/write permission in the whole system (but does he need to have access to mysql command to connect to the database via SSH?)

Comment: Is it just one command that the need to run? Or port-forwarding? Or something else?

Comment: **If you had to** (I don't think you have to, but need clarification of what you are trying to do. See earlier comment), You could protect the `/home` directory by removing `rx` for other. And creating a new group, etc. No need to apply recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What you asked for...

What you are looking for is `chroot`. This will set the `/` root of the filesystem to a location of your choice.

If you `chroot` to `/home/bob` for the user `bob` this location will look like `/` for `bob`. He will not see the rest of the filesystem. Because of this you want to place any programs he needs to run below this folder.

As we now know of `chroot` we can then find plenty of answers and guides:

- [How can I chroot ssh connections?](https://serverfault.com/a/435954/228063)
- [Chroot users with OpenSSH: An easier way to confine users to their home directories](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/)
- [Chrooted SSH/SFTP Tutorial (Debian Lenny)](https://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny)

## What you want...

If the database is accessible from the Debian machine and that is all what is needed then you are looking for a ***SSH tunnel***. You still need to have a user account but this can be locked totally down. The important SSH settings are:

- `AllowTcpForwarding yes` - we are allowed to have a tunnel
- `ForceCommand /bin/false` - if you try to log in via ssh you will not get a shell
- `ChrootDirectory /opt/dummy_location/%u` - If you somehow get a shell anyway we have limited view of the filesystem to an empty location

With this knowledge we can again find plenty of prior art:

- [ssh tunneling only access](https://serverfault.com/a/1013257/228063)
- [How to restrict an SSH user to only allow SSH-tunneling?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176900/74393)

The above handles the ssh connection. If the user has physical access to the server then remember to set the shell for the user as well:

```
usermod -s /bin/false userbob
```

With the above in order then you can search around to see how to connect with any database client. As all the magic with SSH happens on the network layer this can work for all clients! When the tunnel is up it looks like the database is running on the local machine.

Some clients are aware of SSH tunnels and make your life a little easier. A common client would be HeidiSQL - see [How to connect to a MySQL database over a SSH tunnel with HeidiSQL](https://www.enovision.net/mysql-ssh-tunnel-heidisql).

If you go the tunnel route then *please* *please* *please* test with a regular account first to make sure it works **before** you start to lock down the tunnel user!

And finally you should be using **SSH keys** instead of passwords. But this combined with the complexity of chroot is best left as the last thing to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can work from its `/home` directory and there is no need to change dirs this might be a helpful post(not only the answer): [How to limit user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498667/how-to-limit-user-commands-in-linux)
You can also do it with editing `/etc/sudoers` but in your case I think it is not appropriate.

Comment: The user can't work in it's **/home** directory, he doesn't have any write permission but he can read any file from the file system which is the problem