# Using sleep command in ssh authorized_key to prevent user's actions

Tags: ssh, sleep, account-restrictions

I'm setting up an Ubuntu server to receive ssh connections from clients so I will then be able to connect back to their machine (reverse SSH tunneling). I searched for a way to prohibit any action from the client on the server, and I found different solutions, but none seems as simple as just configuring the authorized_key of a specific client on the server by adding:

```
command="sleep x seconds"
```

Am I missing something important that would make that solution not a good one?

Comment: Related but not a duplicate because it doesn't directly address the question asked here [How to restrict an SSH user to only allow SSH-tunneling?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14312/100397)

Comment: Another thing to consider is assigning a "restricted shell" (e.g. "man rbash") for the user used to log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the restriction is for a number of users I would set up a `Match` block in `/etc/sshd_config`, to apply restrictions for that group of users. If the restriction is for a particular ssh key I would consider taking your suggested route and blocking commands in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

**`Match` block in `/etc/sshd_config`**

Read the documentation for `Match`, and as usual when changing how a connection subsystem such as `ssh` works, ensure you have a root login available on the remote system to revert or adjust any changes.

```
# Add users to the UNIX group "restrictedusers"
Match Group restrictedusers
        AllowTCPForwarding yes
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowAgentForwarding no
        ForceCommand echo No logins permitted
```

**Keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`**

Not only force a `command` but also disable X11Forwarding, agent forwarding, etc. by prefixing access control options to an existing or new key entry. Ensure you have a login available on the remote system to revert or adjust any changes to the file.

```
restrict,port-forwarding,command="echo No logins permitted" ssh-ed25519 ed25519-public-key-code-goes-here...
```

In both cases, once this is set up the caller needs to set up the reverse callback for you. For example, this one connects the `remoteHost`'s local port `50123/tcp` to the caller's local port `123/tcp`

```
ssh -fN -R 50123:localhost:123 remoteHost
```

Best of all, this can all be prepared in the caller's `~/.ssh/config` for `remoteHost`, so that they would then just need `ssh remoteHost` to start the callback:

```
Host remoteHost
    ForkAfterAuthentication yes
    SessionType none
    # listenPort targetHost:targetPort
    RemoteForward 50123 localhost:123
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I modified the authorized_keys file based on the example you gave, but when the client connects, the connexion closes immediately (so I'm not able to use the reverse ssh tunnel). That's why I was using "sleep" as a command, as it allows to keep a persisent connexion. If it's not a problem to use "sleep" as command, I will probably use it in /etc/sshd_config ForceCommand instead of using the authorized_keys file.

Comment: Ok now I see, I was not using the -N option when the reverse callback was set up. Thanks!